# Positioning absolute element to stay in the document flow but some way to push elements below

Tags: css, css-position

Please find my script [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7Tz9/5/) showing the problem

Ignore the look & feel, as I had to remove lot of other parts of the page to put it on jsfiddle.

**Facts are**

```
1. Bottom Callout should appear on clicking Latest or Date range
2. On displaying the callout, the buttons should be pushed down accordingly, 
    wrt to the height of the callout
3. The callout is positioned after the Latest/DateRange in order to keep it continuos in the document flow
4. The callout is positioned absolute to avoid the white space that shows next to "Latest",
    this white space is created by the width of the bottom callout if positioned relative.
```

**Problem:** I want to find a way

```
1. to keep the callout in the document flow
2. no white space should be shown next to Latest, when clicking on Latest 
3. the buttons at the bottom should be pushed down rather  than getting hidden.
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas or you need more information on the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are out of the flow, no way to change that. You can either measure the height of the “callout” and set an appropriate height/margin/padding on your list to push the following elements further down while you are displaying it – or you have to find another approach, not including absolute positioning.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I had that as last resort, just wanted to know if there were any other tricky way of achieving the same, anyway settling with that solution now. Thanks for your comments!